# How can I mount my current host directory into a docker container with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Following the official Docs and several blog posts about this topic, I try to mount my current host directory into a docker-container as `/var/www`. However, it will always be empty and files placed in host directory aren't visible nor accessible for Docker.

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.4'
  php:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
    working_dir: /var/www
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
```

In `Dockerfile`:

```
WORKINGDIR /var/www
RUN bin/console
```

will fail due to file does not exist, although it is existing on host directory.

Even when I mount the intermediate container and run `ls -l` on working dir (`ls -l /var/www`) it is empty:

`docker run --rm 1be5bb736ee6 ls -l /var/www`

I run Docker on a Ubuntu 20 machine.

How can I make shared volumes work?

Comment: I'm a little confused why you show the `RUN bin/console` command. It looks like you think that should be run at run-time. It isn't. RUN commands are run at build-time. If there's no need to build the image again, then the command won't be run.

Comment: Also, do you have an `ENTRYPOINT` statement in your dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the files you've shown don't allow us to reproduce your error, I've tried doing what you want to do using `ubuntu:latest`. This works and prints out the contents of the current directory on the host.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  test:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    command: ["ls", "/var/www"]
```